# How can you see the original post when editing?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When I edit some posts (most often questions) for the first time, it's alright because I can open the question in a separate tab and see the original question. But, when I have already submitted an edit and I want to edit that edit because I was mistaken on something or did some error whatsoever, I cannot see the original post without having to log out, see the post, take a screenshot, and log in again.

For example, here I had this question I edited and I replaced the asker's words by some that weren't theirs and I needed to edit the suggested edit to replace my words with the asker's. But, to do this, I needed to see the original question, which was quite annoying to do.

Note : this is only happening when there's no edit history (only 1 edit, the original).

Any clue on how to do this without logging out/in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always click the timeline icon beneath the voting buttons, change the `/timeline` in the URL to `/revisions`, and click the 'Source' link of the initial revision.

But perhaps the most important is that Stack Exchange is not a race; ["we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to useful questions"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) so it usually pays off to review your edit an additional time, to prevent cases like this.